# Multy queryset. Compare two queryset and find compared item

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have one not clearly for me task. I need to find one object which exist in two users.
For example. Each user has `AdditionalInfo`, also i have the table `AddInfoTeam` where i have ManyToMany relationship:

```
class AddInfoTeam(models.Model):
    add_info = models.ForeignKey(AdditionalInfo,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Each user can exist in many teams.

For example i have 2 users - user1 and user2. I need to find out which team are they together.

This is my example code:

```
# get additional info for user1
add_info_dealer = AdditionalInfo.objects.get(user=dealer)
# get additional info for user2
 add_info_grower = AdditionalInfo.objects.get(user=grower)

# get all teams for user 1
 dealer_teams = AddInfoTeam.objects.filter(add_info=add_info_dealer)
# # get all teams for user 2
    grower_teams = AddInfoTeam.objects.filter(add_info=add_info_grower)

# this is bad code, i try to find someting better than this:

    for dealer_team in dealer_teams:
        for grower_team in grower_teams:
            if grower_team.id == dealer_team.id:
                return grower_team
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find with two queries. A similar kind of implementation as yours.

```
add_info_dealer = AdditionalInfo.objects.get(user=dealer)
add_info_grower = AdditionalInfo.objects.get(user=grower)
dealer_teams = AddInfoTeam.objects.filter(add_info=add_info_dealer)
grower_teams = AddInfoTeam.objects.filter(add_info=add_info_grower)
return dealer_teams.intersection(grower_teams)
```